# How to check if field has some a concatenated string of other fields?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make a mysql query that checks that the email field is a concatenated string of firstname zip code last name?  Would something like this do it:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` 
HAVING primary_email 
LIKE 'delivery_first_name . delivery_postal_code . delivery_last_name%'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

should be like this instead

```
select * from orders
where 
primary_email
like concat(delivery_first_name, delivery_postal_code, delivery_last_name, '%');
```

if there is a separator between the column , add in the separator in between these columns